# How to split a Text when detecting String "\n" and a space?

Tags: java, arrays, regex, arraylist, split

for Example

i Have a string like

```
String example = "Hello\nHow\nAre\nyou today? I Love Pizza"; //
```

What i want is an Array like this

```
[Hello, \n, How, \n, Are, \n, you, today? , I , Love, Pizza]
```

I tried Already

```
String[] splited = example.split("[\\n\\s]+");// as will a lot of regular exprisions like ("\\n\\r+")  etc.
```

but they didnt work .

have anyone a solution please ?

Comment: `\s` matches whitespaces which includes `\n` or `\r` or even `\t`. So don't use it if you don't want it to split on `\n`. Use `" "` instead. Now to handle `\n` you can use [look-around](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) mechanism to describe place which has `\n` before or after it.

Comment: The output should contain a space after `today? ` and `I ` ?

Comment: @Pshemo , i tried already " " , but nothing happend , it split with spaces , but not with \\n

Comment: @Thefourthbird no its just a split when space is detected .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it simply by using [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (specified by `?<=`) or lookahead (specified by `?=`) for `\n` and alternated with `\s+` (for whitespace).

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String example = "Hello\nHow\nAre\nyou today? I Love Pizza"; //
        String[] splited = example.split("(?<=\\n)|(?=\\n)|\\s+");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splited));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Hello, 
, How, 
, Are, 
, you, today?, I, Love, Pizza]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split asserting either a newline sequence `\R` on the left or right, or match a horizontal whitespace char `\h` using an alternation `|`

```
(?=\\R)|(?<=\\R)|\\h
```

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/3OZ634)

For example

```
String example = "Hello\nHow\nAre\nyou today? I Love Pizza"; //
String[] splited = example.split("(?=\\R)|(?<=\\R)|\\h");
for (String element : splited) {
    if (element.equals("\n")) element = "newline";
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

Output

```
Hello
newline
How
newline
Are
newline
you
today?
I
Love
Pizza
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Split on the following:
// look ahead for '\n' which is preceded by a character that is not '\n'
// OR look ahead for a character that is not '\n' preceded by '\n'
// OR a single space.
String regex = "(?=\\n)(?<!\\n)|(?!\\n)(?<=\\n)| ";

String example = "Hello\nHow\nAre\nyou today? I Love Pizza";

// This is the array that you want.
String[] splited = example.split(regex);

// This is just to display the contents of 'splited'.
int count = 0;
for (String part : splited) {
    count++;
    if (part.equals("\n")) {
        // Rather than print the actual newline, print its escape sequence
        System.out.printf("%2d. \\n%n", count);
    }
    else {
        System.out.printf("%2d. %s%n", count, part);
    }
}
```

---

Result:

```
 1. Hello
 2. \n
 3. How
 4. \n
 5. Are
 6. \n
 7. you
 8. today?
 9. I
10. Love
11. Pizza
```

Comment: The Probelm is that i want an Array with this answers , and i dont wanna to print "\n"
Thanks for the Answer @Abra